# How to sign in an external ClaimsIdentity using IdentityUser Asp.Net Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2, claims

> **Context Summary**

I'm building a prototype WebApp which I want to integrate to Quickbooks Online.

This WebApp will in turn offer options to call a WebApi that will be responsible to make the requests against the Quickbooks Online WebApi.

In order to achieve this, I registered the Identity services to make it easier for me to have a login process etc.

Now, it seems that I'm confused between Individual Account (IdentityUser) and ClaimsIdentity.

> **Signing In**

When I click the Login option from the top menu, I get correctly redirected to the Quickbooks Online authentication screen where:

- I input my user credentials
- I choose the company I wish to use
- I authorize the WebApp to access the required scopes

On callback, I do a request against the user information endpoint and retrieve all user information needed.

- sub
- givenName
- familyName
- email
- emailVerified

And

- ClaimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated == true

So, I build the list of claims for the ClaimsPrincipal.Identity which just was authenticated externally, and try to sign it in.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
var user = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identities.Single(claimsIdentity => claimsIdentity.AuthenticationType == "ecm-qbo");
user.AddClaim(new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Name, result["givenName"]));
result.ToList().ForEach(kvp => {
    user.AddClaim(new Claim(type: kvp.Key, value: kvp.Value, valueType: null, issuer: "qbo", originalIssuer: "qbo", subject: user));
});
```

But I get this error once my sign process is completed.

[image: Error loading external login information]

What can I do to avoid it, or to correct it so it signs my user in?

> **Code Sample**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o => {
            o.Cookie.Name = "auth_cookie";
            o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;

            o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context => {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(o => {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddOAuth("qbo", "qbo", o => {
                o.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-qbo");
                o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
                o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
                o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "givenName");
                o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "familyName");
                o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "givenName");
                o.ClientId = Configuration["ecm.qbo.client-id"];
                o.ClientSecret = Configuration["ecm.qbo.client-secret"];
                o.SaveTokens = true;
                o.ClaimsIssuer = "ecm-qbo";
                o.Scope.Add("openid");
                o.Scope.Add("profile");
                o.Scope.Add("email");
                o.Scope.Add("com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting");

                o.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["ecm.qbo.authorization-endpoint"];
                o.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["ecm.qbo.token-endpoint"];
                o.UserInformationEndpoint = Configuration["ecm.qbo.user-info-endpoint"];

                o.Events.OnCreatingTicket = async context => {
                    var companyId = context.Request.Query["realmid"].FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("realmId");
                    var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
                    var refreshToken = context.RefreshToken;
                    var tokens = context.Properties.GetTokens();

                    Configuration["ecm.qbo.access-token"] = accessToken;
                    Configuration["ecm.qbo.refresh-token"] = refreshToken;
                    Configuration["ecm.qbo.realm-id"] = companyId;

                    context.Backchannel.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                    context.Backchannel.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    var response = await context.Backchannel.GetStringAsync(context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);

                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
                    var user = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identities.Single(claimsIdentity => claimsIdentity.AuthenticationType == "ecm-qbo");
                    user.AddClaim(new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Name, result["givenName"]));
                    result.ToList().ForEach(kvp => {
                        user.AddClaim(new Claim(type: kvp.Key, value: kvp.Value, valueType: null, issuer: "qbo", originalIssuer: "qbo", subject: user));
                    });

                    await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, context.Principal, new AuthenticationProperties {
                        IsPersistent = false,
                        RedirectUri = "/"
                    });
                };
            });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```